# Using Pandas to drop columns, in a specific row that don't contain a specific substring

Tags: python, pandas, database, dataframe

```
0   a   nan             empty       empty           empty           ... 
1   b   nan 
2   c   nan
3   d   nan
4   e   e.Description   e.Value     e.Attribute     e.Variable      ...     
5   f   nan     nan     nan     nan
```

Above is a picture of a dataframe I've created. I'm attempting to return a dataframe that removes all of the specific variables that contain the substring ".Value, .Attribute, .Variable" in row 4, and leaving all variables that are simply e, and e.Description. A large problem in my dataset is that there are no column names past the second column. And I'm particularly interested in row 4 information.

I've tried many many variations and cannot seem to erase the information in my dataframe. A few examples I've tried are

```
df.drop(list(df.filter(regex = '.Value')), axis=1, inplace=True)
```

I was expecting this to find all substrings of .Value (e.g. e.Value) in row 4 and delete the entire column containing that information from the dataframe. But this is not the outcome I got. My end data frame should look like so.

```
0   a   nan             empty      empty     empty             ...
1   b   nan 
2   c   nan
3   d   nan
4   e   e.Description   e          e         e.Description     ...
5   f   nan     nan     nan        nan       nan               ...
```

I've also attempted to use df.loc[4] to reference the specific row I'm after, but unclear on how to address the information in that row to delete using loc. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `pandas.to_dict()` method to convert your `DataFrame` to a `dict`, and then convert it back to its original state.

With `df` as the variable for your `DataFrame`:

```
import pandas


titles = df.loc[:0]
my_dict = df.to_dict()

for x in titles:
    if my_dict[x][3] == 'e.Description' or my_dict[x][3] == 'e.Variable':
        my_dict.pop(x)
    elif x != 0:
        my_dict[x][3] = 'e'
    

new_df = pandas.DataFrame.from_dict(my_dict, index=False)


print(new_df)
```

The result should be the same, if the numbers themselves are indexes. However, if you want extra indexes, use my previous version of my answer. Otherwise, this should meet your needs.

Thanks for the question!

Comment: Hey 404, I do love the idea of converyting it to a dictionary, but I'm not try to replace the information with e.Description. If there exists a column named e.Description I'm just trying to remove that column entirely.

Comment: Thanks AMetanoia, I have fixed the code. I have a question though. Do you also want to drop e.Variable, or just e.Description?

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
from numpy import nan
import pandas as pd

data_df = pd.DataFrame(
    [
        ["a", nan, "empty", "empty", "empty"],
        ["b", nan, "", "", ""],
        ["c", nan, "", "", ""],
        ["d", nan, nan, "", ""],
        ["e", "e.Description", "e.Value", "e.Attribute", "e.Variable"],
        ["f", nan, nan, nan, nan]
    ]
)
for column_name in data_df.columns:
    data_df[column_name] = data_df[column_name].str.replace("\.Value|\.Attribute|\.Variable", "", regex=True)
```

The results looks like:

```
   0              1      2      3      4
0  a            NaN  empty  empty  empty
1  b            NaN                     
2  c            NaN                     
3  d            NaN    NaN              
4  e  e.Description      e      e      e
5  f            NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN
```

The trick is that you use the str attribute at the column to be able to use the replace method including  regular expression